What security issues could arise from allowing only specific IP access to an open port using UFW on Ubuntu?
I have two hosts running Ubuntu 24.04: Host A and Host B.
On Host B, I have an application that listens on port 7000.
I want to securely connect to this application from Host A while preventing access to Host B on port 7000 from any other host on the internet.
My current plan is:

Configure the application on Host B to listen on 0.0.0.0:7000.
Use UFW on Host B to allow traffic on port 7000 only from Host A's IP address.

I am not concerned about whether the traffic is plain or encrypted for now; my primary focus is on the access control aspect.
Question:
What potential security problems could arise from this approach?
While it seems like a simple solution, I'm worried there may be some downsides or security issues that I'm overlooking.
Any advice on how to mitigate these risks or suggestions for better alternatives would be appreciated.

Do a denial of service attack at Server A, so that it needs to reboot, configure your hacker server with the same IP as Server A, pretend that your hacker server is Server A and connect to Server B. A man in the middle could also just manipulate the packages and replace the sender IP with IP of Server A. Man in the middle is always total overkill.

better alternatives IPSEC has been around for 20 years. More organizations use IPSEC than using firewalls for address-based access control.
